# Which functions are predefined in JCL TEvaluator class

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Does anyone know which predefined functions (e.g ABS function) are included in the `TEvaluator` JCL class for Delphi 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are none of the standard functions from `Math.pas` included. All that is implemented in the default evaluation parser are the operators `or`, `xor`, `and`, `not`, `mod`, `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `=`, `div`, `cmp`, `bor`, `bxor`, `band`, `bnot`, `shl`, and `shr`. (As many as I found in a quick check of the source, and a few I missed based on @David's comment.)

You can add functions (including those that are part of the Delphi RTL) to the evaluator fairly easily. It's even shown in the demo, which adds the functions from one of the JCL units.

The JCL evaluator example (ExprEvalExample.dpr) found by default in the `JCL\examples\common\expreval` folder passes a `TComboBox.Items` to the `Init` function in `ExprEvalExampleLogic.pas` as the `FuncList` parameter, which is populated by this code (the `TEasyEvaluator` is given the functions in the same routine) with the functions from `JclMath.pas`:

```
  with FuncList do
  begin
    Add('LogBase10');
    Add('LogBase2');
    Add('LogBaseN');
    Add('ArcCos');
    Add('ArcCot');
    Add('ArcCsc');
    Add('ArcSec');
    Add('ArcSin');
    Add('ArcTan');
    Add('ArcTan2');
    Add('Cos');
    Add('Cot');
    Add('Coversine');
    Add('Csc');
    Add('Exsecans');
    Add('Haversine');
    Add('Sec');
    Add('Sin');
    Add('Tan');
    Add('Versine');
    Add('ArcCosH');
    Add('ArcCotH');
    Add('ArcCscH');
    Add('ArcSecH');
    Add('ArcSinH');
    Add('ArcTanH');
    Add('CosH');
    Add('CotH');
    Add('CscH');
    Add('SecH');
    Add('SinH');
    Add('TanH');
  end;
```

Those would be the functions supported in the demo app. You can add your own in a similar fashion.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you repeated my answer, and then added loads of extra content unrelated to the question.

Comment: When I originally posted my answer, it was before your edit (at the time it didn't even include the information about the supported operators), and your "It is trivially easy" sentence was much different. I posted the list of the base operators, a reference to the demo to see how to add them, and sample code from that demo that showed how. I don't quite understand your objection; you do it all the time (repeat what others have already said, phrased differently, and with additional details). It's a substantial part of the rep you've accumulated (as is taking other's comments as your answers.

Comment: The edit history to my answer doesn't agree with what you say. And I'm not going to bite on your final sentence. Anyway, looks like the voters preferred your version!

Comment: FWIW, you missed out the following: `div`, `cmp`, `bor`, `bxor`, `band`, `bnot`.

Comment: It seems that or, xor, not, mod and and functions are not predefined... I checked them and got "Undefined symbol" error...

Comment: @ssnkh: Check the source; according to it, they are indeed supported (as are the few I missed that David pointed out). There's a comment around line 44 (search for `operator priority`) that lists it. There's also a declaration of `function modulo`.

Comment: I just looked at the example that contains that excerpt of code because I happen to be working on expression evaluation today. That's a horrible violation of DRY in that `Init` procedure.

Comment: @David: Yes, it is. :-) I didn't write it, though.

Answer (score 3):

No predefined functions are included. There are the standard arithmetic operators: +, -, *, div and mod. And there's all the standard logical and bitwise operators. But nothing like abs, sin, exp, log etc. You have to put those in yourself. It is trivially easy to add functions and I think it's a good design to let you choose exactly what your evaluator supports.